Is it correct to use the verb ''translate'' in this way?
I am reading a mechanics book [Vector Mechanics For Engineers by Beer and Johnston tenth ed]. The author wants to tell us that a force can be represented geometrically using the size of its components or the angles between the force and the coordinate axes. This is the sentence used by the author:

It makes sense that, for a given geometry, only
a certain set of components and angles characterize a given resultant force.
The methods in this section allow you to translate back and forth between
forces and geometry.

This screenshot is taken from the Intended page:


If the use of this verb in this text is correct, then what can be its exact meaning؟ I looked at several dictionaries and this is the meaning I thought was suitable:

convert or be converted into (another form or medium), express by a different medium or mode of expression.

Is this what the author meant?

Please do not post images like that. People with low vision cannot see them and in any event, you do not need three images. Why would a sentence from a native speaker of that ilk that be wrong? It isn't.

Yes, "express by a different medium or mode of expression" (from the one into the other or the other way around)

It can be confusing because "translate" also has a specialized meaning in geometry, about "moving" an object. But you've got the right idea. A similar phrase might be code-switch.

No.  'translate' is not used correctly as far as I am concerned.  And this is a technical, engineering or mathematical usage and typically not covered by this forum.
Geometry can be used because of the physics involved.  In the case shown, the problem is Statics (fancy word for no movement) which means that the sum of the forces is zero and the sum of the moments is zero.  Those physics laws determine how the geometry can be used.   There is no "translate back and forth" just because the problem can be solved with geometry -- once you understand the physics.
Vector mechanics can be "reduced" to geometry in special cases.  However that is one-way -- not back and forth.
I did search Dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster for a suitable definition.  I did not find one.
I also opened several text books looking for something along the lines of the above and -- again -- did not find any references that would indicate that the use of "translate" in this instance was correct.

The phrase translate back and forth roughly means find equivalence.
The second quoted sentence hence means

The methods in this section allow you to [find equivalence] between forces and geometry.

It's also possible to use this meaning:

convert or be converted into [another form]

(I have deleted medium, which doesn't apply here.)
That second quoted sentence becomes

The methods in this section allow you to [convert forces into geometry].

